# can't find any package that provides Email-Sender

Tags: perl, activestate

While installing Perl Packages for bugzilla it is giving error as..

```
Command:ppm install Email-Sender 
Error:ppm install failed:can't find any package that provides Email-Sender
```

Comment: `ppm install Email::Sender` [Please refer for further more explanation](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Sender-1.300031/lib/Email/Sender.pm)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to do it from within CPAN?

> cpan > install Mail::Sender

Comment: try updating CPAN and reloading it. From within CPAN's console, `install CPAN`, then `reload CPAN`. Then try again `install Mail::Sender`

Comment: @Ruchira More, "Still not working" is not an adequate description of a problem. What error did you get?